# ffmpeg Will stream be copied if same codec is requested?

Tags: ffmpeg

I loop over some files and convert them with ffmpeg. I provide `-vcodec h264`. When the input video already is encoded with that codec: will the video stream be copied? How to make sure it's not reencoded in that case? Is it what `-sameq` was used previously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `-c:v copy` if you want the raw H.264 stream to be passed on without re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i myh264file.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy myh264output.mp4
```

`-c:a copy` will also copy the audio

`-c copy` will copy both audio and video as in:

```
ffmpeg -i myh264file.mp4 -c copy myh264output.mp4
```

Detecting H.264 streams is not straight forward. You will need to code this.

For the `-sameq` settings please refer to [this statement](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Why-was-the-ffmpeg-_002dsameq-option-removed_003f-What-to-use-instead_003f).

I would recommend upgrading to a recent version of ffmpeg if it is not already done as `-vcodec` is not used anymore, now it is `-c:v`.

The [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) on ffmpeg could help you.